# How do I get 500 IP address?

Tags: networking, ip-address, subnet

128.100.112.0/21 block of IP addresses granted by a company. Company said this block of addresses must be divided into four subnetworks that have each at least 500 IP addresses.

**How do I get 500 addresses from the IP block?**

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) has a specific section about that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your informations is not so correct, see it: https://ipinfo.io/AS239/128.100.0.0/16

You can scrap this website. Or [WHOIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS) records using [WHOIS requests](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215842648-How-to-run-a-WHOIS-query).